# generate daily report with laravel mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I want  to make each `row` gets all records from same day even if i added record later with an old date. echo day and number of customers that submitted in that day .

If i changed the column to `id` instead of `created_at` it works fine but when it comes to date gets me all records even though that created_at and `$yDay` and `$tDay` same date structure. 
i still didn't code the days counter . btw am still beginner at laravel 
Thanks you in advance .

```
$yDay = Carbon::now()->subDay()->toDateTimeString();
$tDay = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
$rows = DB::table('customers')->whereBetween('created_at', [$yDay,$tDay ])->get();
```

Comment: Where's the problem? Is there an error or your code didn't work the way you want?!!! Please help us help you.

Comment: code doesn't work the way i want it

Comment: Consider changing your question title to something like *Laravel/Carbon select rows by Date*. The current title could make a reader think this is about a cronjob or a scheduling problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want your data date wise,  but you are fetching your data based on datetime.

I guess below code will solve your problem -

```
$yDay = Carbon::createFromDate(date('Y, m, d', strtotime(Carbon::now()->subDay()->toDateString())), Carbon::now()->tzName);

$tDay = Carbon::createFromDate(date('Y, m, d', strtotime(Carbon::now()->toDateString())), Carbon::now()->tzName);

$rows = DB::table('customers')->whereBetween('created_at', [$yDay,$tDay ])->get();
```

Comment: thanks for responding but i got Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Trailing data
 :(